How to match std::stringstream through AST?
Target code block:
int age = 5;
std::stringstream q;
q << "my name "
<< "is Tom, "
<< "my age is " << age;

I'm trying to create a matcher to match the entire block from the second line.
I tried a very case specific matcher, but it does not work.
My goal is to match similar code blocks, where the LHS and RHS number is not fixed.
cxxOperatorCallExpr(hasOverloadedOperatorName("<<"),
  hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(expr(anyOf(
    stringLiteral().bind("firstString"),
    stringLiteral().bind("secondString"),
    stringLiteral().bind("thirdString"))))),
  hasRHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(expr(anyOf(
    declRefExpr(to(varDecl(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("std::stringstream")))))),
    declRefExpr(hasType(isInteger())))))))

I tried to test from finding the line std::stringstream q; with varDecl(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("std::stringstream")))), but it returns empty as well.
How should I start or even how to build a matcher based on the ast dump log?
Appreciate any help.

Match a variable declaration of type std::stringstream
Starting with the second question, to match a variable declaration of
type std::stringstream, use a
Clang AST matcher
like this:
varDecl(
  hasType(
    asString("std::stringstream")
  )
)

The asString matcher turns the type into a string, making it
reasonably easy to use.
The attempted matcher in the question:
varDecl(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("std::stringstream"))))

fails for a few reasons:

The sequence hasType(cxxRecordDecl(...)) will never match because
cxxRecordDecl matches a declaration (a piece of syntax) while
hasType matches a types (an abstract semantic notion).  You would
need to at least insert hasDeclaration between the two, but that
cannot be directly applied until the kind of type has been further
refined, since not all types have declarations.

The actual type in this case is an
ElaboratedType,
which Clang seemingly sprinkles throughout its Type structures in a
way I find somewhat unpredictable.  That makes it hard in general to
match Types.

The type to which the name std::stringstream refers is a
TypedefType
for a template specialization, rather than a stand-alone class, so
cxxRecordDecl won't match.  (Note: TypedefType is used for type
aliases created with either typedef or using.)


If you want to match a declaration of a std::stringstream variable
without using asString, use this more complicated matcher:
varDecl(
  hasType(
    elaboratedType(
      namesType(
        typedefType(
          hasDeclaration(
            namedDecl(
              hasName("std::stringstream")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

Match operator<< applied to a stringstream
Armed with the above, we can try to match a use of operator<< where
the left-hand side is a stringstream.  The question has this example
expression:
q << "my name " << "is Tom, " << "my age is " << age;

This is parsed as a nested tree of binary operators:
(((q << "my name ") << "is Tom, ") << "my age is ") << age;

So we need to look for a use of operator<< where somewhere in the
left-hand side is a stringstream, and the right-hand side is either a
string literal or an integer-valued expression (I'm partly guessing the
intent based on the attempted matcher in the question).  That can be
done like so:
cxxOperatorCallExpr(
  hasOverloadedOperatorName("<<"),
  hasLHS(
    hasDescendant(
      expr(
        hasType(
          asString("std::stringstream")
        )
      ).bind("stringStreamExpr")
    )
  ),
  hasRHS(
    ignoringParenImpCasts(
      expr(
        anyOf(
          stringLiteral(
          ).bind("stringLiteral"),
          expr(
            hasType(
              isInteger()
            )
          ).bind("intExpr")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

This will separately report matches for each occurrence of operator<<.
It does not try to report a single match for the entire compound
expression with all of the various arguments at once; the AST matcher
language is not really powerful enough to do that robustly.
Complete example
Here is a shell script that runs
clang-query
with the above matcher:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/d/opt/clang+llvm-18.1.8-msvc/bin:$PATH

matcher='
  cxxOperatorCallExpr(
    hasOverloadedOperatorName("<<"),
    hasLHS(
      hasDescendant(
        expr(
          hasType(
            asString("std::stringstream")
          )
        ).bind("stringStreamExpr")
      )
    ),
    hasRHS(
      ignoringParenImpCasts(
        expr(
          anyOf(
            stringLiteral(
            ).bind("stringLiteral"),
            expr(
              hasType(
                isInteger()
              )
            ).bind("intExpr")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
'

clang-query \
  -c "set bind-root false" \
  -c "m $matcher" \
  test.cc --

# EOF

Test input file test.cc:
// test.cc
// Match an `operator<<` expression involving `std::stringstream`.

#include <sstream>                     // std::stringstream

void f()
{
  int age = 5;
  std::stringstream q;
  q << "my name "
  << "is Tom, "
  << "my age is " << age;
}

// EOF

Output of the script:
Match #1:

$PWD\test.cc:12:22: note: 
      "intExpr" binds here
   12 |   << "my age is " << age;
      |                      ^~~
$PWD\test.cc:10:3: note: 
      "stringStreamExpr" binds here
   10 |   q << "my name "
      |   ^

Match #2:

$PWD\test.cc:12:6: note: 
      "stringLiteral" binds here
   12 |   << "my age is " << age;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
$PWD\test.cc:10:3: note: 
      "stringStreamExpr" binds here
   10 |   q << "my name "
      |   ^

Match #3:

$PWD\test.cc:11:6: note: 
      "stringLiteral" binds here
   11 |   << "is Tom, "
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
$PWD\test.cc:10:3: note: 
      "stringStreamExpr" binds here
   10 |   q << "my name "
      |   ^

Match #4:

$PWD\test.cc:10:8: note: 
      "stringLiteral" binds here
   10 |   q << "my name "
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
$PWD\test.cc:10:3: note: 
      "stringStreamExpr" binds here
   10 |   q << "my name "
      |   ^
4 matches.

Issues with the matcher in the question
The question has this attempted matcher:
cxxOperatorCallExpr(hasOverloadedOperatorName("<<"),
  hasLHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(expr(anyOf(
    stringLiteral().bind("firstString"),
    stringLiteral().bind("secondString"),
    stringLiteral().bind("thirdString"))))),
  hasRHS(ignoringParenImpCasts(expr(anyOf(
    declRefExpr(to(varDecl(hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("std::stringstream")))))),
    declRefExpr(hasType(isInteger())))))))

This has several problems worth identifying as part of clarifying how
the AST is structured and how matchers work:

It seems to be looking for string literals on the left-hand side
and stringstream variables on the right-hand side; those should
be swapped.

It is trying to match multiple string literals inside anyOf, but
anyOf will stop after the first branch succeeds.  If you change that
to allOf, then all of the bindings will just go to the same
expression.  In some cases, forEachDescendant can be used to do
something like this, but I find it difficult to use robustly, and it
would not apply here (or at least I don't see how to make it work in
this case).

It seems to expect the entire statement to be a single
cxxOperatorCallExpr, but it's actually a tree of them.

It has the issues with recognizing stringstream variables explained
in the first part of this answer.



Thank you very much for this informative response. I’m still learning about the AST in Clang, but I find it quite ambiguous to create a matcher from an ast dump output.  What would you suggest as the best approach for creating a matcher based on an AST dump output?

It's hard to give general advice since it's a broad topic.  The Clang docs have Matching the Clang AST that gives a brief overview.  Beyond that, trial and error, along with asking questions here about specific examples, and also reading existing Q+A tagged with "clang-ast-matchers", is what comes to mind to suggest.
